# KnockoutJS in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm facing a problem building a SPA with knockout!
I got multiple ViewModels for one View!

In this jsFiddle everything works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/11/

But as soon as I try to use these in ASP.NEt it doesnt work anymore!

I tried it like this:

```
<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }"> 
              //Some Code
</form>

<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }">
              //SOME CODE
</form>

<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }"> 
              //Some Code
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var masterViewModel = {

            loginVM: ko.observable(),
            detailsVM: ko.observable(),
            projectStartVM: ko.observable()

        };

        var LoginVM = function () {
             //Some Code
        };

        var DetailsVM = function () {
          //Some Code

        };

        var ProjectStartVM = function () {
           //Some Code

        };

        masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM());
        ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Anybody knows what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What  does "it doesnt work anymore" mean? Did you get any exception on client or server side or knockout logic doesn't work correct?

Comment: Have you referenced knockout in your view/layout?

Comment: yes i have referenced it in my View!

The binding itself works!

It should be like every ViewModel has opens one part of the view and the rest is hidden (If you try the fiddle you'll probably understand what i mean).
In the ASP.Net it shows the whole page, and the functions don't work anymore (But the binding works)